# SQL to update rows to remove words with less than N characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, insert-update

I have a `TAGS` column in my `Products` table in SQL Server. In my web project I split them with space, for example:

```
"web web_design website website_design"
   =>  1.web  2. web_design 3. website ......
```

How I can remove words with less than N characters from tags? Is it possible with a regex?

For example if N=4 so "web" will be removed from my example and the rest remains.

Comment: You should really fix your design; then the matter is as simple as `DELETE FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE LEN(Tag) < @N;`

Comment: You should have a `Tags` *table* then as mentioned this becomes trivial; by storing delimited values your data does not even conform to 1NF. You will need to split your data into the rows it should be, filter, then re-concatenate it. Better, use this as an exercise to fix it permanently!

Comment: *"Is it possible with a regex?"* No, or at least not natively in SQL Server; it has no inbuilt support for Regex. Just another, of many, reasons why you need to fix your design.

Comment: Since "fixing the schema" is an unlikely path at this point, your only option is to split the strings and then recombine the ones you want. Suggestions for doing both of those tasks can be easily found with simple searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give a solution to do this without changing your design at the bottom of this answer,

but I really think you should fix the design, here is an example on how to do that.

It starts from a table called "mytable" that has your "tag" column with all the data,
then it creates a detail table and populates it with the splitted values from your tag column
and then it is very easy to do what you want to do

```
create table tags (id int identity primary key, mytable_id int, tag varchar(100))

insert into tags (mytable_id, tag)
select t.id,
       value
from   mytable t
  cross apply string_split(t.tag, ' ')

alter table mytable drop column tag
```

See a complete example [in this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=06d389a2f263859f894493a3ae85d408)

**EDIT**

if you need to show it again as if it where in one table, you can use `string_agg` like this

```
select m.id,
       m.name,
       ( select string_agg(t.tag, ' ')
         from   tags t
         where  t.mytable_id = m.id
       ) as tags
from   mytable m
```

You can see this at work in [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e272872dd4fa42239fcca2b497608f97)

**EDIT 2**

And if you really want to stick to your design, here is how you can remove the words from your tag column

But I recommend not doing this, as you can see in the examples above it is not so hard to fix the design and create a new table to hold the tags.

```
update m
set    m.tag = 
       ( select string_agg(value, ' ')
         from   mytable t
           cross apply string_split(m.tag, ' ')
         where len(value) > 3
         and   t.id = m.id
       ) 
from   mytable m
```

Look at [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=71d25ae00dcd3b2aaaa2bc7aa4af6e09) to see it in action